# Sort array by month and total value from dates - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have this type of json data, I need to sort this data by months on given dates with total calculated values.

```
[
{
    "value": "123",
    "date": "01/01/2020"
},
{
    "value": "342",
    "date": "12/01/2020"
},
{
    "value": "432",
    "date": "23/01/2020"
},
{
    "value": "123",
    "date": "01/02/2020"
},
{
    "value": "123",
    "date": "01/01/2020"
},
{
    "value": "322",
    "date": "16/02/2020"
},
{
    "value": "643",
    "date": "26/02/2020"
}
]
```

I wanted to sort new data like this in new array

```
[
 {
  "value": "1020", // total count of values
  "date": "Jan" // month in string
 },
 {
  "value": "1088", // total count of values
  "date": "Feb" // month in string
 }
]
```

I am using moment.js for converting dates

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what do you think a possible approach should be? What functions are involved?

Comment: I tried with foreach loop, but not getting proper values

Comment: Can you post at least your attempt. You've posted 2 blocks of JSON (1 invalid) that don't appear to be related to each other

Comment: You've not stated any clear rules about why you have dates in *some* format in the first block, and month names in the second block

Comment: its just a sample data for understanding

Comment: But it doesn't help anyone understand what you're trying to achieve. 1) What are the data types in the first block? `Date` objects or strings in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"? 2) Why do you have the date format "mmm" in the second block? Are you saying the first block should be grouped by month, then sorted by month and value? If so, that's an important distinction to make in your question. 3) What if you have data from different years? What are the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an input array in the format:

```
[
  { 
    date: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    value: number
  }
]
```

And you want to transform it into an array of grouped objects:

```
[
  {
    month: "MMM",
    value: SUM(Values in month)
  }
]
```

The key parts here will be the `reduce` array function and the `Map` object.

#### Create a map of months

Use the `reduce` function to create a map of months and summed values. You can loop through the array once, and save the values to a map, updating the value as you go.

```js
const map = this.data.reduce((map, current) => {
  const month = this.getMonth(current.date);
  const key = month.toISOString();
  if (!map.has(key)) {        
    map.set(key, 0);
  }      

  map.set(key, map.get(key) + current.value);
  return map;
}, new Map<string, number>());
```

Where `this.getMonth(date)` is some mapping function. I am using a regex, but you can replace this with moment if you wish.

```js
private getMonth(dateString: string): Date {    
  const dateRegex = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
  const match = dateRegex.exec(dateString);

  return new Date(
    parseInt(match[3]),
    parseInt(match[2]) - 1,
    1
  );
}
```

#### Sorting the months

Next, you can create an array of sorted months from the map you created in the last step. The key is an ISO string, so sort using string comparison.

```js
const months = Array.from(map.keys())
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

#### Mapping the result

Now you can map from the sorted months to the final output using the `map` function.

```js
months.map(x => ({
  month: formatDate(x, 'MMM', 'en-US'),
  value: map.get(x)
}));
```

I am using the `formatDate` function from `'@angular/common'` here. This is the modern alternative to injecting the `DatePipe`. I am using the `en-US` locale because that is supported out of the box. You can also use moment.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc6ktd

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = [{"value":123,"date":'01/01/2020'},{"value":342,"date":'12/01/2020'},{"value":432,"date":'23/01/2020'},{"value":123,"date":'01/02/2020'},{"value":123,"date":'01/01/2020'},{"value":322,"date":'16/02/2020'},{"value":643,"date":'26/02/2020'}];
const toDate = str => new Date(str.replace(/^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/, "$2/$1/$3"));
const month = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
const map = data.reduce((a,b) => {
  const m = toDate(b.date).getMonth();
  a[m] = a[m] ? +a[m]+b.value : +b.value;
  return a;
}, {});
const res = Object.entries(map).map(([key, value]) => ({value, date: month[+key]}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi, how can we use two different value like value1 and value2 ex. {"value1":123, "value2":342, "date":'01/01/2020'} in this code?